# Cutting lots of polylines using single horizontal line in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have 2000 polylines or more, each polyline have about 2000-3000 vertices. I want cut all part of polylines that are below a single horizontal line. How can I do that in Arcgis?[image]

I try to use intersect tool: polylines layer with the layer horizontal line (with output "point"). In this way I obtain points intersection, I can use it to split the polylines and finally I can delete all polylines below the horizontal line by simply selection the area. The problem is that the first step, intersecate polylines with the single horizontal line, take an infinte process. My idea isn't good, is there another fast solution?

Comment: Intersection with output=point should take few seconds. Are they in the same protection? Are geometries correct? The idea is correct.

Comment: Alternatively make polygon going up and use it as clipper

Comment: @FelixIP can you explain me with steps how use clipper?

Comment: Ok, done. Clipper is super fast!

Comment: @FelixIP I think your clipper comment with just a little expansion would make a good answer

Comment: @lausent:I think you can't never cut polylines thgrough only one line, but with polygon you can, If I were you I will use Erase (Analysis) tool

Comment: @PolyGeo where is my sticker for getting rid of un-answered Qs? My granddaughter won't understand it:)

Comment: @FelixIP she may not understand it but we call that sticker [Access to Moderator Tools](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and it comes when your accelerating rep reaches 10,000 (not long now).

Answer (score 1):

- Extend your Split (single) line to the West, beyond left most line
- Extend your Split (single) line to the East, beyond right most line
  [image: Inputs]

The next two steps are for lazy person and keeping programming in mind:

```
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management("Many Lines","D:/Scratch/rectangle.shp", "RECTANGLE_BY_AREA", group_option="ALL")
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(in_features="rectangle;'Single Line'", "D:/Scratch/splitRectangle.shp")
```

OUTPUT CONTAINS 2 POLYGONS:
[image: OUTPUT]

Select lower polygon and use it for Erase tool with lines to be split, alternatively select upper one and use it for Clip tool.